# Ionic 2 can't register custom html tag

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2, components

I'm running into an issue with `Ionic 2` and `custom components`. I created a `component` to display in a list. The component is the list item. The issue is when I attempt to use the custom html tag my app crashes. I added my stack trace below. I'm not sure what the issue is. I followed this guide from the [angular 2 documents](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) but the code doesn't seem to work. 
Thank you for any help

custom component file

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {EventInfo} from '../../../models/event-info';

@Component({
    selector: 'event-item',
    templateUrl: 'event-item.html'
})
export class EventItemComponent {
    @Input() eventInfo: EventInfo;

    constructor(){

    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the custom tag in my home.html file

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
        <event-item [eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
    </div>
```

Here's my stack trace from the browser

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'eventInfo' since it isn't a known property of 'event-item'.
1. If 'event-item' is an Angular component and it has 'eventInfo' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("n-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            <event-item [ERROR ->][eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:24
'event-item' is not a known element:
1. If 'event-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <ion-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            [ERROR ->]<event-item [eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:12 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError {_nativeError: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'eventInfo' since it isn't a known property of 'event-it…} Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'eventInfo' since it isn't a known property of 'event-item'.
1. If 'event-item' is an Angular component and it has 'eventInfo' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("n-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            <event-item [ERROR ->][eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:24
'event-item' is not a known element:
1. If 'event-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <ion-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            [ERROR ->]<event-item [eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:12
    at v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4864)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107253:27)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11219:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:26474:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71153:68)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71036:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71036:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:70918:19)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9655)
    at e.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7019)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4661
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10284)
    at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7637)
    at i (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3707)
o @ polyfills.js:3
r @ polyfills.js:3
i @ polyfills.js:3
polyfills.js:3 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'eventInfo' since it isn't a known property of 'event-item'.
1. If 'event-item' is an Angular component and it has 'eventInfo' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("n-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            <event-item [ERROR ->][eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:24
'event-item' is not a known element:
1. If 'event-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <ion-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            [ERROR ->]<event-item [eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:12
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'eventInfo' since it isn't a known property of 'event-item'.
1. If 'event-item' is an Angular component and it has 'eventInfo' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("n-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            <event-item [ERROR ->][eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:24
'event-item' is not a known element:
1. If 'event-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <ion-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            [ERROR ->]<event-item [eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:12
    at v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4864)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107253:27)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11219:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:26474:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71153:68)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71036:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71036:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:70918:19)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9655)
    at e.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7019)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4661
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10284)
    at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7637)
    at i (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3707)
    at v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4864)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107253:27)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11219:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:26474:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71153:68)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71036:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71036:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:70918:19)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9655)
    at e.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7019)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4661
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10284)
    at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7637)
    at i (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3707)
    at v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4864)
    at s (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4289)
    at s (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4112)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4652
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10284)
    at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7637)
    at i (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3707)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to import your EventInfo component into your app.module.ts file as an EntryComponent and declaration according to #2 in the error log.

```
2. If 'event-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("n-list *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let item of eventList._events">
            <event-item [ERROR ->][eventInfo]="item"></event-item>
        </div>
        <!--<ion-card>-->
"): HomePage@43:24
```

import like so

```
import {EventInfo} from '../../../models/event-info';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ...
     EventInfo
     ...
   ],
  entryComponents: [
     ...
     EventInfo
     ...
   ]
})
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it pointed me in the right direction but was slightly off, but that's only because of my project structure. The project template I am using has a `multiple modules`structure within in. So instead of `declaring` it with the app.module, I needed to `declare` within the `home.module.ts` Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue and it's taken me a while to figure it out. 
I used the CLI tool to generate the custom component, which seems to have a slight issue.
In my `custom-component.module.ts` the generator had added

```
...
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
...
imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(CustomComponent),
  ],
...
```

Changing these lines to

```
...
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
...
imports: [
    IonicModule,
  ],
...
```

Fixes the main issue.
To use `<custom-component>` in a page's HTML you then have to import the `custom-component.module` into the page module where you want to use it. 
For example if you wanted to use your component on the home page edit
`home-page.module.ts`

```
...
import { CustomComponentModule } from "../../components/custom-component/custom-component.module";
...
imports: [
    CustomComponentModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(JobsPage),
  ],
...
```

And that seems to work for me! I think once all the lazy-loading is implemented and the CLI generators are working properly Ionic will be much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **item-content** attribute on any element inside list item template. It will work.

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-card item-template *ngFor="let item of items">
    <img ion-img item-left src="ion-list"/>
    <div item-content> any content you want... </div>
    </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

[image]